# blockchain_import fails, "Transaction has too many dirty pages - transaction too big"

Tags: monerod, lmdb

I'm trying to set up a node and import the raw blockchain. OS is Whonix with 2GB RAM and plenty of free disk space hosted on Win7 ENT.

```
user@host:~/Desktop/monero$ ./blockchain_import --input-file blockchain.raw 
2016-Aug-30 08:49:32.647152 Starting... 
2016-Aug-30 08:49:32.647493 Setting log level = 0
2016-Aug-30 08:49:32.647768 database: lmdb
2016-Aug-30 08:49:32.647991 database flags: 0
2016-Aug-30 08:49:32.648241 verify:  true
2016-Aug-30 08:49:32.648461 batch:   true  batch size: 100
2016-Aug-30 08:49:32.648719 resume:  true
2016-Aug-30 08:49:32.648939 testnet: false
2016-Aug-30 08:49:32.649200 bootstrap file path: blockchain.raw
2016-Aug-30 08:49:32.649422 database path:       /home/user/.bitmonero
2016-Aug-30 08:49:32.694990 Loading blockchain from folder /home/user/.bitmonero/lmdb ...
2016-Aug-30 08:49:52.389821 [batch] DB resize needed
2016-Aug-30 08:49:52.390331 LMDB Mapsize increased.  Old: 2048MiB, New: 3072MiB
2016-Aug-30 08:49:52.692956 Blockchain initialized. last block: 85100, d807.h17.m53.s22 time ago, current difficulty: 380438790
2016-Aug-30 08:49:52.743456 bootstrap file recognized
2016-Aug-30 08:49:52.743530 bootstrap file v0.1
2016-Aug-30 08:49:52.743559 bootstrap magic size: 4
2016-Aug-30 08:49:52.743585 bootstrap header size: 1024
2016-Aug-30 08:49:52.743615 Scanning blockchain from bootstrap file...

Done scanning bootstrap file
Full header length: 1028 bytes
Scanned for blocks: 3292602310 bytes
Total:              3292603338 bytes
Number of blocks: 1123182

2016-Aug-30 08:51:06.203899 bootstrap file last block number: 1123181 (zero-based height)  total blocks: 1123182

Preparing to read blocks...

2016-Aug-30 08:51:06.230419 bootstrap file recognized
2016-Aug-30 08:51:06.230464 bootstrap file v0.1
2016-Aug-30 08:51:06.230488 bootstrap magic size: 4
2016-Aug-30 08:51:06.230511 bootstrap header size: 1024
2016-Aug-30 08:51:06.230538 start block: 85101  stop block: 1123181
2016-Aug-30 08:51:06.349911 Reading blockchain from bootstrap file...

block 85170 / 1123181 2016-Aug-30 08:59:17.317979 Error attempting to retrieve an output pubkey from the dbMDB_TXN_FULL: Transaction has too many dirty pages - transaction too big
2016-Aug-30 08:59:17.339632 Output does not exist! amount = 20000000000000
2016-Aug-30 08:59:17.342223 Output does not exist! amount = 60000000
2016-Aug-30 08:59:17.353337 DB error attempting to fetch block index from hashMDB_TXN_FULL: Transaction has too many dirty pages - transaction too big
2016-Aug-30 08:59:17.353715 exception while reading from file, height=85177: DB error attempting to fetch block index from hashMDB_TXN_FULL: Transaction has too many dirty pages - transaction too big
2016-Aug-30 08:59:17.354055 Closing IO Service.
```

I saw (probably) this reported as an yet [unresolved open issue](https://github.com/monero-project/bitmonero/issues/855) on ARM7 and I understand that it is an `lmdb` issue. Any suggestion how should I continue with setting up my node/wallet?

Answer (score 6):

It appears that you're using a 32bit build. This was a known bug in the 32bit LMDB code, [Issue #855](https://github.com/monero-project/bitmonero/issues/855), fixed on August 11 in [commit 7442dd084acfcef571c51f53277247c050d1c98b](https://github.com/monero-project/bitmonero/pull/955/commits/7442dd084acfcef571c51f53277247c050d1c98b).

Comment: Well the version I've downloaded is monero.linux.x64.v0-9-4-0.tar.bz2 which should be 64 bit, how do I find out whether the included `blockchain_import` was compiled as 64 or 32 bit?

Comment: file blockchain_import

Comment: @user36303 can you please explain your comment?

Comment: It was an answer to your question above. You can determine whether blockchain_import is a 32 or 64 bit binary (or another type of file altogether) by running `file blockchain_import`.

Comment: @user36303 Got it, thanks, yes I am using a 32 bit build